# Create individual rows based on sum value for fake dataset

Tags: r

I am creating a fake dataset, and would like to essentially disaggregate a sum to create dummy rows that I can populate with random dates.

For example, my `df` might look like this:

```
id    orders   skips
joe   3        0
mary  2        1
jack  5        1
```

I want to produce is a `data.frame` or `data.table` that looks like this, where a successful `order` is `1` and a skip is `0`:

```
id    order
joe   1
joe   1
joe   1
mary  1
mary  0
mary  1
jack  1
jack  1
jack  1
jack  1
jack  0
jack  1
```

**ADDITION:** Ideally, the `0` values would be randomly mixed/sandwiched between `1` values if possible. This is due to a quirk of what the dataset will be used for in a problem set.

In a perfect world, I'd then assign a random `start_date` from a given range to each order within `id`, such that:

```
id    order  date
joe   1     1/2/2016
joe   1     1/3/2016
joe   1     1/8/2016
mary  1     1/10/2016
mary  0     1/3/2016
mary  1     1/5/2016
jack  1     1/7/2016
jack  1     1/2/2016
jack  1     1/1/2016
jack  1     1/10/2016
jack  0     1/12/2016
jack  1     1/15/2016
```

I initially thought that I could use a combination of `dcast` and `reshape` to trick R into making the dataset, e.g.`dcast(df,id~orders,fun.aggregate=length)` but this took me down the wrong path.

But, one must walk before they crawl. Anyone able to help?

Comment: @josliber I've added a few of my ideas (`dcast` and `reshape`) but didn't want to send anyone down a rabbit hole that I knew to be wrong. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: `x <- Vectorize(rep)(setNames(rep(1:0, nrow(df)), rep(df[, 1], each = 2)), (t(df[, -1]))); data.frame(id = names(x), order = x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach with `data.table`:

```
dt[, .(order = rep(c(1, 0), c(orders, skips))), by = "id"]
#      id order
#1:   joe     1
#2:   joe     1
#3:   joe     1
#4:  mary     1
#5:  mary     1
#6:  mary     0
#7:  jack     1
#8:  jack     1
#9:  jack     1
#10: jack     1
#11: jack     1
#12: jack     0
```

---

**Data:**

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread(
  "id    orders   skips
  joe   3        0
  mary  2        1
  jack  5        1"
)
```

Comment: Not in my question now (I'll go back and edit), but do you have any thoughts on how I could make it so that the 0's are in middle rows when possible? e.g., row #6 would be row #5.  This is a quirk of the problem that the fake dataset will be used for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in base R using `tapply` (or `split` and `lapply`, if you prefer) and then `rbind`ing everything back together:

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind, tapply(df, df$id, 
                             function(x){
                                 data.frame(id = rep(x$id, sum(x$orders, x$skips)), 
                                            order = sample(rep(c(1, 0), c(x$orders, x$skips)))
                                 )
                             }))
rownames(df2) <- NULL
```

where `tapply` runs the anonymous function across groups of `df$id`, and `do.call(rbind,` rearranges the list back into a single `data.frame`. The anonymous function makes a `data.frame` by `rep`eating `id` the necessary number of times and using `sample` to shuffle 0 and 1 `rep`eated `orders` and `skips` numbers of times, respectively.

One hiccup, which should be fixable: `rbind` automatically creates row names, which are ugly and unnecessary. There is an argument to turn this off, but I can't get it arranged in the `do.call` structure properly, so the above just erases them in a second line. (If you know the right place to stick `make.row.names = FALSE`, comment and I'll edit.)

The result:

```
> df2
     id order
1  jack     0
2  jack     1
3  jack     1
4  jack     1
5  jack     1
6  jack     1
7   joe     1
8   joe     1
9   joe     1
10 mary     1
11 mary     0
12 mary     1
```